# How to know the size of a table with a photo in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table that I fill in the post method, I send a photo, and describe the event, I want to know the size of this table (MB) with the help of a selector, Someone can help me with this ??

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE image
  2  (
  3     Neme        VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     EVENT_ID    VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     MYFILE      BLOB
  6  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In oracle, to find out the size of your table, you can do this:

```
select segment_name
       , segment_type 
       , SUM(bytes/1024/1024) MB
from dba_segments
where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='IMAGE'
GROUP BY segment_name
         , segment_type;
```

And here is a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=469552670167216162ba0169078110a2) if you use a user_segments instead of dba_segments as a_horse_with_no_name suggested.

And if you would like to check your BLOB column size try this:

```
SELECT SUM(DBMS_LOB.GetLength("MYFIL")/1024/1024) AS SizeMB
FROM IMAGE;
```

Comment: Cool. Why did you accept the answer if it doesn't work, then? By the way, *why* doesn't it work? How do you know? Are you allowed to query DBA_ objects?

Comment: It gives the error, "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" although this table exists !!

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak I have changed my answer, try to do it again - with capital letters for the table name...

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak You need to use `user_segments` instead of `dba_segments`

Comment: Yes, I believe that `user_segments` will work because you get `table or view does not exist` error. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. If you post your own answer I will vote up. Cheers!

Comment: @VBoka  yes after i used "user_segments" the command worked but the answer is not correct !! There are 109 photos in my table, but my answer is "MB = .0625". It is impossible! –

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I noticed the size "MB = .0625" in all my tables!

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak , check this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69655aaed88c0fb6e06944539d858608 You will see that size of the table is bigger that 0,0625 if it has more than 1000 rows even when it has empty BLOB and number column. At the end of this demo you will see an example of the code that you can use to see the size of your BLOB column.

Comment: @VBoka Yes, I tried, but it didn't help, the answer didn't change((((Nothing fits.

Comment: @VBoka ,Sorry I didn't notice you changed your answer, your answer (drga part) helped me a lot! But I understand that this query is for one column, and can I make this query for a table as a whole ??

Comment: Yes, and the first query is for the entire table. You can use : dba_segments or user_segments table in that query. If you want to check size in this way column + column + column... Then check my exaple at the end of this DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fefe35a0fba848caa872793fa66e66e0

Comment: Also, I would appriciated it if you vote up my answer and accept my answer as correct. Vote up = this answer is helpful. Cheers!

Comment: @VBoka If I use your request, then my (0.625) MB answer is untrue (((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203101/discussion-between-vboka-and-andrii-havrylyak).

Comment: @VBoka Thank you